# Let $L$ be the line of intersection between two planes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $L$ be the intersection between two planes:
\begin{align*}
x - 3y - 3z &= 4\\
2x - y + 2z &=4 
\end{align*}

a) find a vector $v$ parallel to $L$.

For this question, I wrote it as an augmented matrix and reduced it to reduced row-echelon form to get $x = 9/5 - 9t/5$ and $y = -2/5 - 8/5t$ and $z = t$. And then the vector form equation is $$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}9/5\\ -2/5\\ 0\end{pmatrix} + t\begin{pmatrix}-9/5\\ -8/5\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Not sure what to do next, I put $t = 1$ to find $v = (0, -2, 1)$ but it's incorrect.

b)  Find the cartesian equation of a plane through the point $(2,−1,−3)$ and perpendicular to L.

For this question, I am lost.

Comment: For part a) L should be perpendicular to normal of both the planes so a vector along it would simply be cross product of vectors i-3j-3k and 2i-j+2k.

Comment: Hello :) For the a) part: The way, you did it, is almost correct :) There is a mistake in the calculation of the row echelon form. (I don't know where, because you didn't write any calculations.) The vector, which is parallel to the line $L$ is only the vector after the $t$. Here it would be $v=(-9/5, -8/5, 1)$, if you had calculated it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align*}
x - 3y - 3z &= 4\\
2x - y + 2z &=4 
\end{align*}$

Your approach for the first part is fine but your answer is incorrect for the given planes.

As the line $L$ is on both planes, it will be perpendicular to normal vectors of both planes. Normal vectors are $(1, -3, -3)$ and $(2, -1, 2)$ and the cross product is $(-9, -8, 5)$. Also setting $z = 0$, we see point $\left(\frac{8}{5}, - \frac{4}{5}, 0\right)$ is on both planes.

So equation of line is, $\frac{x - 8/5}{-9/5} = \frac{y+4/5}{-8/5} = \frac{z}{1}$

Any vector of the form $ \lambda(-\frac{9}{5}, - \frac{8}{5}, 1)$ is parallel to $L$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is a scalar.

For the second part, the normal vector to a plane which is perpendicular to the line $L$ is going to be parallel to the direction vector of the line, which is $(-\frac{9}{5}, - \frac{8}{5}, 1)$.

We also know that equation of a plane with normal vector $(a, b, c)$ passing through point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is given by $ a(x-x_0) + b(y-y_0) + c (z-z_0)=0$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

For part b) you know that the plane passes through (2,-1,-3) ,also the required plane is perpendicular to the line L . Hence, a vector along L would be  a normal to the plane.( If you know that ai+bj+ck is a normal vector of a plane P, then the Cartesian equation of the plane can be written as ax+by+cz=d where 'd' is some arbitrary constant which can be found out using the fact that the plane passes through (2,-1,-3) ...you just need to substitute in the equation of plane, x by 2,y by -1 and z by -3 in the equation of plane). So you get the equation of the plane.

Answer (score 0):

For part (a), the line of intersection of the two planes is perpendicular to their normal vectors, therefore, it is in the direction of the cross product of the two normal vectors.

$n_1 = (1, -3, -3) , n_2 = (2, -1, 2) $

$n_1 \times n_2 = (-9, -8, 5 ) $, is a vector parallel to the intersection line.

For part (b), the equation of the plane is

$ (-9, -8, 5) \cdot (x - 2, y + 1, z + 3) = 0 $

which simplifies to,

$ -9 x - 8 y + 5 z + 25 = 0 $